# What is the correct way in C# to parse this date format "Mon Oct 07 00:00:00 EDT 2013"?

Tags: c#, json, datetime, json-deserialization, jsonserializer

I am getting a json message from a server and I am trying to parse it into C# objects.  I am [using the RestSharp Deserializer](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization). There is one field that is not properly converting into a datetime:

the string value of the field in this message is:

```
"createDateTime":"Mon Oct 07 00:00:00 EDT 2013"
```

on my object I have this as:

```
public DateTime? createDateTime { get; set; }
```

NOTE: that is a nullable DateTime because something the field is blank

but when I do this:

```
var deSerializer = new JsonDeserializer();
var response = client.Execute(request);
var responseObj = _deSerializer .Deserialize<Response>(response);
return responseObj;
```

I realized the root cause is that the DateTime.Parse is failing.  I tried adding this which causes it to use

```
   DateTime.ParseExact()

  _deserializer.DateFormat = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
```

but I then get an error stating:

**String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

so this all comes down to how in C# to parse a date coming in as this format

```
   Mon Oct 07 00:00:00 EDT 2013
```

Comment: The JSON format for that date is `"2013-10-06T15:00:00.000Z"`. Perhaps the source of your JSON is serializing the dates incorrectly?

Comment: you might want to try manually parsing your date using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @matthew5025 - see my updated question.  I have added a specific dateformat which looks like its doing the same thing as you suggest but i am getting an exception listed above

Comment: @JLRishe - I have updated the question to focus simply on the DateTime.ParseExact question as the issue seems lest about the json deserialization and more about simply how I can parse a date that comes in that format

Comment: Three letter timezones? Good luck! http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since in my case I don't really care about time and the timezone is always in EDT, i wrote this to get around this issue in the short term.

```
    private DateTime? ParseMe(string s)
    {
        var split = s.Split(new[] {' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var year = int.Parse(split[split.Count()-1]);
        var day = int.Parse(split[2]);
        var month = split[1];
        int monthInDigit = DateTime.ParseExact(month, "MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month;
        return new DateTime(year, monthInDigit, day);
    }
```